Error when using simulate for bootstrapping
I am trying to implement some parametric bootstrapping for a bunch of simple models, so I defined a function bootstrap.para(model, data) which takes a model and the corresponding data the model is based on and goes through the following steps:

extracts some info about the model for later model fitting and creating matrices for storing the results
creates empty matrices for storing the results later
goes nboot (= number of bootstrap iterations) times through a loop and simulates new response variables, re-fits the model and stores info about the new model in the results-matrices

This is the original code within the function:
# fit the model (this would normally be provided to the function)
model <- glm(survival ~ 1, data = current_data, family = "binomial")

# get model family (poisson, binomial, gaussian) and response variable
family_type <- family(model)$family
response_variable <- as.character(best_model$formula[[2]])

# make matrix to store bootstrapped results and a vector to store sigma
boot_results2 <- matrix(NA, nrow = nboot, ncol = length(coef(model)))
sigma_results2 <- numeric(nboot) 


for (b in 1:nboot) { # for each bootstrapping iteration...
  # simulate new response data based on the model's coefficients
  simulated_data <- data
  inbetween <- simulate(trial)
  simulated_data[[response_variable]] <- inbetween$sim_1
  
  # refitting the model to the simulated data
  new_model <- glm(formula(model), 
                   data = simulated_data, 
                   family = model$family)
  
  # store the coefficients
  boot_results2[b, ] <- as.vector(coef(new_model))
  sigma_results2[b] <- sigma(new_model)
}

However, I really struggle with the simulate() function: At random iterations - sometimes the first, sometimes later - simulate()throws the following error:

Error in factor(1 + rbinom(ntot, size = 1, prob = ftd), labels = levels(y)) :
invalid 'labels'; length 2 should be 1 or 1

Weirdly enough, when I then manually assign the "problem iteration", i.e. b = 1 or whenever the problem happens, I can run though the loop just fine and simulate() works alright. Has anyone else ever run into problems with this function? Or what could be the problem?
I tried debugging it by freshly assigning the model for every iteration of the loop, printed info about the model and data (factor levels etc.) in every iteration and so on, but couldn't detect any patterns.
This is some of my data:
current_data <- dput(dat_stack)
structure(list(treat_comp = c("bare", "bare", "bare", "bare", 
"bare", "bare", "bare", "bare", "bare", "bare", "bare", "bare", 
"bare", "bare", "bare", "bare", "bare", "bare", "bare", "bare", 
"bare", "bare", "bare", "bare", "bare", "vege", "vege", "vege", 
"vege", "vege", "vege", "vege", "vege", "vege", "vege", "vege", 
"vege", "vege", "vege", "vege", "vege", "vege", "vege", "vege", 
"vege", "vege", "vege", "vege", "vege", "vege", "vege", "vege", 
"vege", "vege", "vege", "bare", "bare", "bare", "vege", "vege", 
"vege", "vege", "vege", "vege", "bare", "bare", "vege", "vege", 
"vege", "bare", "vege", "vege", "vege", "bare", "bare", "vege", 
"vege", "vege", "bare", "bare", "bare", "vege", "vege", "vege", 
"bare", "bare", "bare", "bare", "bare", "vege", "vege", "bare", 
"vege", "vege", "vege", "bare", "bare", "bare", "vege", "vege", 
"bare", "vege", "vege", "vege", "bare"), treat_warm = c("ambi", 
"ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", 
"ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", 
"ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", 
"ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", 
"ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", 
"ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", 
"ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", 
"ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", 
"ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", 
"ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", 
"ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", 
"ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", 
"ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi", "ambi"
), survival = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), biomass_t0_log = c(-1.38863091244406, 
-2.39785233402159, -1.44978666120658, -1.17429480174161, -1.55624837589942, 
-2.42114432335448, -3.77776459265706, -1.56487729774059, -3.64983110773459, 
-3.90725301933214, -0.943607808276286, -2.09647087885028, -1.48987549419745, 
-1.97409963578281, -2.00294281391662, -0.790987836006535, -1.27126934379116, 
-0.917511254629111, -0.891772007535876, -1.64273972161791, -2.09114005889827, 
-1.3448839031686, -0.242650524732129, -0.383109734441139, 0.391755898380763, 
-2.91872140222755, -3.98658360452609, -2.97892173076763, -1.62366716492636, 
-2.68088307757302, -2.750824373309, -3.5684638304626, -2.2781091539448, 
-1.84454669549673, -2.14205724230953, -3.44214950193079, -2.14909670801103, 
-2.57436642786154, -2.96887809308382, -2.35535778581836, -2.24507736996415, 
-2.02233230644035, -2.7060863833494, -1.68085205387831, -2.16980815430938, 
-2.05592876075148, -4.12875642598269, -2.28144406620843, -2.09664022812501, 
-1.76272280678903, -1.94566263345346, -4.18107188912413, -2.14914741219812, 
-2.72668381275279, -3.21543548827711, 1.50509957748387, 0.21897823546132, 
3.10390601358911, -0.00364720860562682, -1.62955109343176, -1.3007612187993, 
-2.47710636111218, -4.32604314362071, -2.68968225349518, -0.0793168051886201, 
1.76316639061886, 0.850651738432455, -0.370084274758356, 0.2010130553872, 
0.346013111165195, -3.54987824849302, -1.88336383272196, -1.70304160420178, 
0.122753388539573, -2.29791229217956, -2.69054383365046, -0.922683708454314, 
-2.86431259805348, 1.55058299416695, 2.05596546304879, 1.58897684200824, 
-1.83815086220367, -1.97811222706951, -0.62353985333176, 1.26425652389913, 
1.40702958276596, 1.22500256945267, -0.461746884476552, 1.40909499369555, 
-0.529857158848436, -2.93402478036734, -1.43154303992316, -2.86214957453668, 
-4.3254293776865, -3.15991706383974, 0.954243038163724, 0.939724394556167, 
-3.59629304915133, -2.41955808747117, -2.87935262168098, 0.935367752749175, 
-0.778681463749543, -2.90873674963124, -1.18033665533509, -0.991463219612599
)), row.names = c(NA, -105L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))


Here is a possible solution.
Call the model refit glm with tryCatch and keep the error. Then, after the for loop you can test the results for errors.
Also, you had too many instructions in the loop, I have simplified it a bit.
model <- glm(survival ~ 1, data = dat_stack, family = "binomial")

response_variable <- as.character(model$formula[[2]])
fam <- family(model)$family
sim_data <- dat_stack

nboot <- 100L
sim <- simulate(model, nboot, seed = 2024L)
sim_list <- vector("list", nboot)

for(i in seq.int(nboot)) {
  sim_data[[response_variable]] <- sim[[i]]
  sim_list[[i]] <- tryCatch(
    glm(model$formula, sim_data, family = fam),
    error = function(e) e
  )
}
err <- sapply(sim_list, inherits, "error")
sim_ok <- sim_list[!err]

Created on 2024-10-10 with reprex v2.1.1

Thanks! The weird in-between steps were trials to fix the problem, but you're right, they can be deleted. I also have added a tryCatch before, but couldn't find any patterns. What finally worked was transforming the response variable to numeric - but I have no idea why this only caused problems in some iterations and so inconsistently - which is why I never even thought about a solution like this.
